# Making heading staying in the middle of top border

Tags: css, css-position

I saw some designs like this and wonder if it is possible to recreate with CSS?
Are there any tweaks with negative values required?
Here is the code example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <h1> HEADING </h1>
 <dic class="square"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
 }

.square {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks ✌️
[image: reference]

Comment: Miggle? Also, there are hundreds of questions about how to center things using CSS. Have you tried anything? Do you have any code that you've started on?

Comment: I've add an example, thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put the heading in the 'square' div so that it is relative to the 'square' div. The solution I chose was to make the heading `position: absolute;` and eventually I gave it `top: -40px` so that it peaks out.
You can also use `margin-top: -40px` instead of `position: absolute;` but it's just what you prefer.

Final code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  color: black;
 }

.square {
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.text{
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="square"> 
    <h1 class="text">HEADING</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be more flexible to set `line-height:1; margin:0; top: -0.5em;` - that way, the top would adjust to different font sizes.